React 19 useActionState form - preserve input values after submit?
Is there a build-in way to preserve user input in form?
Currently after form submit it's removed.
For example in case of error I don't want to removed it.
export default function Route() {
    const [state, action, isPending] = useActionState(
        async (_prev, formData) => {
            return loginAction(formData);
        },
        null,
    );

    async function loginAction(formData) {
         // login
         return {token:'smth'} // or {error: 'smth'}
    }

    return (
            <form action={action}>
                <input type="text" name="email" />
                <input type="text" name="password" />
                <button type="submit"> Login </button>
            </form>
    );
}

